# How do I get the really cool "Smart" Google on desktop?

Tags: google-search, google-now

If I google "make a meeting for 5pm tomorrow" on a desktop computer, I get this:

[image: screen shot of search]

But if I search that on my phone's Google app (the built in one) I get this:

[image: screen shot from phone]

(Sorry the image is so big it's just what it gave me when I held Home + Power. Also, the word "Make" is the first word there, you just can't see it because the search bar isn't big enough.)

Anyway, how do I get this on desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's **Google Now**, and it's [currently available in the Google Chrome beta channel](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/articles/18544/20130627/google-now-chrome-android-ios-features-web.htm). You'll have to use Chrome as your browser if you want that feature.

See also: [Google Chrome Blog: Richer notifications coming to Chrome](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2013/05/richer-notifications-coming-to-chrome.html)

Comment: I can't find the plugin, it just leads to a chrome download page (I am using chrome to access it, it's my default browser). Do you know where to find it?

Comment: It's not an extension; it's built in to the browser. You have to be on the beta channel.